# How resolve Deployment when we change server

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, sql-server-2008-express

i built an application using sql server express , Wpf and LINQ To sql 
the problem is if we change the server  we are obliged to change the connection  string used in all the application .
if we create another database in an other machine the problem will be resolve when we just cut and paste the new connection string
i read that when we work with sql server express this will not be possible??
i am asking you for some tips to resolve this problem

Comment: Do you not just store the connection string in your config file?  It's standard practice where I work to have different config files for different environments.

Comment: can you explain more this my first project using Visual Studio and sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the server, and you can do a DNS redirection to new one, that solve your problem. Otherwise you will have to re-redistribute your application.

Comment: if we create a new server and i give him a new alias it works?? @Oscar

Comment: See this similar question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24809/deprecating-sql-server-need-to-redirect-clients-to-new-server
And this Microsoft documentaction about C names: https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20ARCserve%20Replication%20and%20High%20Availability%20Option%20for%20Windows%2015-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/SQL/index.htm?toc.htm?743652.html

Comment: no this can not be a solution for my problem so what do you think about working with external app.config files

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "external app.config".. App config files can't be "externals", by definition they must reside in the same folder than the application itself.

Comment: i mean something like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: i will proceed by replacing the name of server in all the solution Perhaps this is the only solution

Comment: I don't know how you're distributing your software, but for desktop applications, clickonce is very helpful in this cases..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31313/discussion-between-gasroot-and-oscar)

Comment: no problem i changed the server name by localhost and it works very well